# Django won't import values to database - sqlite3

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I am trying to put values to my django database.

My app_name/models.py looks like:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Language(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    code = models.TextField(max_length=14)
```

I ran this commands:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations app_name
python3 manage.py migrate app_name
```

After that I starting importing values to my database. So I run this command:

```
python3 manage.py shell
```

and put this code to the shell:

```
from app_name.models import *

with open('lang.txt', 'r') as file:
    for i in file:
        a = Language.objects.create(code=i.strip())
```

File lang.txt contains 309 lines with language codes. The file looks like:

```
en
fr
af
de
...
```

When I run this code in the manage.py shell Django created 309 Language objects. But when I try type random id  in the shell -> `Language(id=1).code` it return only empty string - `''`.

I tried use save() method too but still same problem.

```
from definitions.models import *

with open('lang.txt', 'r') as file:
    for i in file:
        a = Language(code=i.strip())
        a.save()
```

Django version 1.10.1

So my question is where can be a problem?

Comment: Do you get an empty string using `Language.objects.get(id=1)`, too?

Comment: No, I see text what I excpected. Why get() method shows right string and Language(id=1).code shows empty string? Thanks

Comment: That's the way Django interacts with the db. Using the [`objects.get`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) method. I think its time for reading ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are not fetching `Language` objects properly.

When you do `Language(id=1).code`, You are instantiating Language object with no value in given to code field.

In django, to fetch a object, you do `Model.objects.get(field=value)`. So your code becomes:

```
Language.objects.get(id=1).code
```